# Python restart for loop

Tags: python

I have this script:

```py
from sys import argv
from tokens import Token
from os import system

file = open(argv[1], "r")
script = file.readlines()
lines = script

file.close()

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line[:8] == Token.INCLUDE:
        system("python3 {} {}".format(argv[0], argv[1]))

        del lines[index]
        restart_loop() # Code block to restart the loop
```

and how can I restart the for loop. (Extra information: Token.INCLUDE = "`%include`")

Comment: Why are you calling `del lines[index]`?

Comment: To delete the `index`th element from `lines` list

Comment: if you delete the lines that satisfy your condition, what's the point of running the loop again?

Comment: to interpret the other lines of input script

Comment: I'm making a interpreter and this ```python
if line[:8] == Token.INCLUDE:
        system("python3 {} {}".format(argv[0], argv[1]))

        del lines[index]
        restart_loop() # Code block to restart the loop
``` is for importing a library etc.

Comment: but those lines *necessarily* won't meet the conditions that trigger your code to run them

Comment: well I'm still working on

Comment: In other words, after you delete the lines where `line[:8] == Token.INCLUDE` is True, all you have left is lines where `line[:8] != Token.INCLUDE` is True

Comment: I'll add other keywords like `if` `else`

Comment: The thing is, you really don't want to modify a list as you iterate through it. There are a ton of questions on stackoverflow that explain how this leads to unexpected and undesirable behavior. With more context, I promise you, folks here could suggest a simpler way to achieve your goals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By restart the loop i'm assuming u mean call it again

the easiest way to do is would be to make it a recursive function

```
def fn(): 
     for index, line in enumerate(lines):
         if line[:8] == Token.INCLUDE:
             system("python3 {} {}".format(argv[0], argv[1]))

             del lines[index]
     #make sure to add your conditions else it will go into an infinite loop. 
     fn()
```

Comment: I did edit it, can you check again you answered true?

Comment: yep looks like ur trying to call a recursive function try the code snippet i answered with it should work, all u have to do is replace ur for for loop and call the function

Comment: @maDeveloper I didn't downvote, but your question lacks a lot of detail and context. Also your example code isn't runnable and you don't show even a sample of the contents of the file. Thus, people who answer questions have to do a lot of guess work

Comment: The down votes were since the question asked wasnt formed well and simialr questions were asked before, it actaully happens alot @maDeveloper ive gotten tons of downvotes

Comment: Hmm I got it, thanks you anyways I'll try your answer